# GeoTrellis and GeoPySpark - TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: pyspark, geotrellis

I'm new to GeoTrellis, and had a question about the example script in the geopyspark readme: https://github.com/locationtech-labs/geopyspark.

Here's an abbreviated version of the script (we'll call it example.py):

```
import json
from functools import partial

from geopyspark.geopycontext import GeoPyContext
from geopyspark.geotrellis.constants import SPATIAL, ZOOM
from geopyspark.geotrellis.geotiff_rdd import get
from geopyspark.geotrellis.catalog import write

from shapely.geometry import Polygon, shape
from shapely.ops import transform
import pyproj


# Create the GeoPyContext
geopysc = GeoPyContext(appName="example", master="local[*]")

# Read in the NLCD tif that has been saved locally.
# This tif represents the state of Pennsylvania.
raster_rdd = get(geopysc=geopysc, rdd_type=SPATIAL,
uri='/tmp/NLCD2011_LC_Pennsylvania.tif',
options={'numPartitions': 100})
```

I'm able to run this on an EMR cluster using `python3 example.py`, but when I try and run `spark-submit example.py`, I get TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable.

This seems to point to this line in geopyspark/geotrellis/geotiff_rdd.py:
`geotiff_rdd = geopysc._jvm.geopyspark.geotrellis.io.geotiff.GeoTiffRDD`

Is there any way I can run this code using `spark-submit`? Based on what I've read, it seems that I can't run my code on a cluster using `python example.py`. Is this the case? And if so, how can I get around this issue to run GeoPySpark code on a cluster?

Should I just learn scala and use that instead?

Answer (score 3):

@charlie-hofmann. I'm one of the developers of GeoPySpark, and can give you some help.

The first thing I'd like to point out is that we just released GeoPySpark v0.2.0 yesterday, and with that release came some major changes to the API which are not reflected in your example code. We've since updated, that example which will work with the 0.2.0 release.

The error that you were facing early was indeed caused by not having the backend jar installed (it needs to be downloaded separately due to size limitations on PyPi), but as you later found out does not work when trying to run the code on EMR. If you're familiar with Docker, we have a container that has the environment needed to run GeoPySpark, including on EMR.

It can be downloaded via this command:

`docker pull quay.io/geodocker/jupyter-geopyspark`

One way we deployed EMR in the container was by putting the binary dependencies into an archive that was passed to `spark-submit`. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with EMR so I can't provide much help beyond that. We do have a [repository](https://github.com/lossyrob/foss4g-2017-geopyspark-workshop) that contains examples of using GeoPySpark on EMR, though. In addition, we have a [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/geotrellis/geotrellis) where developers who are more knowledgeable about this topic can answer your questions.

I'm sorry for not being able to answer all of your questions, but I at least wanted to provide some assistance.

Best,

Jake

Comment: Link to updated example: https://github.com/locationtech-labs/geopyspark#a-quick-example

Comment: Link to the docker container repository: https://github.com/geodocker/geodocker-jupyter-geopyspark

Comment: thanks so much for your help on this @jbouffard-- I'll start an EMR cluster now and test!

Comment: Having some issues understanding how jupyterhub, docker and emr all interact-- will work on this more then reach out in gitter if I have further questions. Thanks again for your help @jbouffard!

Comment: You're welcome, @charlie-hofmann!

The Jupyterhub provides a means to visualize and analyze your data in a more interactive way, though, is not required. While the docker container contains an environment that is already setup to use GeoPySpark on both a Jupyter Notebook and on EMR.

Please feel free to ask us any questions you may have!

Best,

Jake